# Problems on boot

Tags: boot, laptop, 13.04, acpi, grub-efi

Good morning! I have a little problem with my Ubuntu 13.04. Actually, I have this problem with any other linux distributive (Fedora, Fuduntu, Mandriva, Ubuntu 11.04 => 13.04, Linux Mint 14 and oth.). 
Heres what happened: when the computer is start, I have a little blink on the display. It seems like some process crashed. Everything works fine after that, but I am afraid of my notebook.

Notebook: ThinkPad X220 42990 rv5

Here`s log:

```
Tablet kernel: [   12.294342] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.539310] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.543377] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.564252] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.566920] mei 0000:00:16.0: setting latency timer to 64
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.566983] mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.567186] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.578325] wmi: Mapper loaded
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579449] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.PMIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579456] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579462] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579465] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579489] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579493] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579494] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579497] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.579498] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.584168] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.584175] checking generic (e0000000 130000) vs hw (e0000000 10000000)
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.584177] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.584216] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
```

May  1 11:03:49 Tablet kernel: [   12.584306] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with KVM. I don't know why, but it burst my display. So, I turned off virtualisation technology in BIOS, and it helps. So, if anyone has this problem too, you can do the same till Ubuntu geeks will fix this problem.